# How to install MySQL-python on Amazon Web Services EC2 instance?

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, setup.py

I have a EC2 instance created on AWS and use PuTTY to connect to it.
I'm unable to install ***MySQL-python*** using python ***pip*** command as follows:

***pip install MySQL-python***(via root privileges)


Here is the console output of the error

```
Collecting MySQL-python
Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
sh: mysql_config: command not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
File "/tmp/pip-build-JGbAEI/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
metadata, options = get_config()
File "/tmp/pip-build-JGbAEI/MySQL-python/setup_posix.py", line 43, in get_config
libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
File "/tmp/pip-build-JGbAEI/MySQL-python/setup_posix.py", line 25, in mysql_config
raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found
----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-JGbAEI/MySQL-python
```

However I'm able to install other packages using ***pip***

Please Guide.

Comment: See if the link here does the trick for you: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/52548990/7305166](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52548990/7305166)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`mysql_config` is available after installation of the following package on Amazon Linux:

```
sudo yum install -y mysql-devel
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like mysql_config is missing, so make sure mysql_config is really installed.

For example on Debian/Ubuntu you must install the package:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```